# Keep child position the same after parent moved with CSS transform

Tags: html, css, transform, css-animations

Is it possible to take a child outside of the flow of its transformed parent? Simple example below:

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="button">Move parent</a>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    width: 200px;
}

.child {
    background: black;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
}

.moved {
    transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('test');
    $('.parent').toggleClass('moved');
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ous3s873/1/

Very simple stuff. Basically, the parent (red box) is being moved 100px to the right using a CSS transform. My desired output is that the child (black box) would stay in the same place as the parent moves behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is adding a negative `translateX` to the child element in order to make it stay at its place:

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/ous3s873/2/)**

```
.moved .child {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
}
```